# s:Rotate3D with constant rotation speed

Tags: android, apache-flex, flash-builder

I am new in the Flex and Flash Builder, so sorry for stupid questions :).

What I am trying to make is an Android App. Clock, with an image that makes a full rotation cycle every 20min.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:Rotate3D 
            id="rotateEffect"
            target="{clock}"
            angleZFrom="0"
            angleZTo="360"
            repeatCount="999999999"
            duration="1200000"
            autoCenterTransform="true"
            />
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:actionContent>
        <s:Button click="NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit()" icon="assets/appi_11.png"
                  styleName="title"/>
    </s:actionContent>
    <s:Image id="clock" horizontalCenter="0" source="assets/rotateMe.png" verticalCenter="0" click="rotateEffect.play()"/>
</s:View>
```

Problem is, that there is some kind of easing behaviour and speed of rotation is not constant.

Is there any way that I can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the specificity of Flex or Flash Builder. It sounds like that the animation is not played at "real-time" which depends on how the system handles it. In general, you want to rotate the clock (arms) in accordance to the time difference between current (system) time and the start time (that you saved in a variable). So the clock will run properly independent of how often the system updates the canvas.

Comment: Thanks! 
I will try to learn how to do that :). I am sadly rubbish with a code, and since "Rotate3D" have duration ver. i thought that I could use it for a quick solution.